# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, eclipselink, hibernate-entitymanager

I have an application using JPA and i am trying to deploy it on a Tomcat 7. It seems that I didn't include all the libraries correctly since I get the stack error mentioned below. But when i run as a java application it compiles correctly.

Basically, my servlet calls `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT)`

with the factory, it calls `factory.createEntityManager()` and with the entity manager, it will try to persist an object made with the parameters from Http request.

The server is raising an exception of

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence`.

when I call the 
first method to get the factory from Persistence. Here is the stack:

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at dao.ImplementDao.<clinit>(ImplementDao.java:18)
    at controller.ListServlet.<init>(ListServlet.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:71)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and this my POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MonProjet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpaProjet</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jpaProjet</name>
    <description>jpaProjet</description>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net.m2</id>
            <name>java.net m2 repo</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>deprecated</id>
            <name>JBoss Deprecated</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>EclipseLink</id>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-RC1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Javaee API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate-entitymanager</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA-brew</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**EDIT:**

WEB-INF/Lib :
[image]

Comment: check in WEB-INF/lib folder if the jar file exist

Comment: see the edit i will show you tle lib folder

Comment: I meant inside the tomcat where you have deployed the war file.

Comment: You dont have all the required jar files. Which persistence provider you are using?? If you are using eclipselink then add all other jars

Comment: apparently you're trying to use "persistence-api" v1.0 (i.e JPA 1.0) with EclipseLink that supports JPA 2.1. Use consistent API with consistent JPA implementation before doing anything else. I'm sure any docs for your JPA implementation would say the same